# Memory allocation for local String literals?

Tags: java, string, memory, garbage-collection

I know that when we create string literal, it goes inside permgenspace. My question is will it lie there for the life time of jvm even if that string literal is local to method. For example  i have below code snippet:-

```
private static void testString1(){
        String str1="tetingLiteral";
    }


private static void testString2(){
        String str2="tetingLiteral";
    }
```

now from main method i call

```
testString1();
testString12();
```

will str1 and str2 will refer to same memory location.

My understanding is They will refer to same memory location(even if string literal is created inside method, it will stay there for lifetime of jvm). But still wanted to confirm it as i could not check it programmatically becoz no way to print string memory location

Comment: There are two ways of getting information about a string memory location. (1) == comparison of two String references is true if they are both null or both refer to the same String object. (2) `System.identityHashCode`, as far as possible, returns a different value for each distinct object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [section 3.10.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

(And see the example below, which shows that string interning works between classes in different packages, too.)

Answer (score 5):

The exact implementation is JVM specific but in Oracle Java 7, the string literals are on the heap and can be cleaned up when no class uses the string literal (as they have been unloaded)

Comment: Does it mean they will be cleaned up alongwith normal GC run?

Comment: I suspect they will only be cleaned up on a Full GC.  In Java 8 the permgen will be removed and classes will be on the heap as well.

Comment: Peter one more thing it would be helpful to know reason why java 7  stores string literal on heap(is it becoz string literal are one of the biggest contributor of permgen error)? Also  why  in Java 8 the permgen will be removed and classes will be on the heap as well?

Comment: sorry for asking too much.But as you gave brand new info, could not resist myself from asking this

Comment: AFAIK, There is a feeling that tuning two spaces is too complicated for many.  Using a single heap simplifies the designed and tuning.  In JEE systems the permgen can easily fill up.  IMHO using a minimum if simple libraries is a good thing which has a benefit of never filling your perm gen.